# EF Core TPH Discriminator ignores base entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two DbContext. A `BaseDbContext` and one that inherits from the `BaseDbContext`called `FemaleDbContext`.

```
public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<House> House { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person", "dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<House>().ToTable("House", "dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOne(e => e.House).WithMany(e => e.Persons);
        modelBuilder.Entity<House>().HasMany(e => e.Persons).WithOne(e => e.House);
    }
}
```

The goal is to extend the `Person` entity with another property. I do not want to use shadow properties because its too dynamic. So I am trying to make it work using TPH. Here is my other context:

```
public class FemaleDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Female> Female { get; set; }

    public FemaleDbContext(DbContextOptions<FemaleDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Female>().HasBaseType<Person>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

As you can see, my sub-context should use the `Female` entity instead of the  `Person`. The problem is that when I run `this.Context.Female.ToList()` on my SubDbContext, only entities with the value `Female` inside the `Discriminator` field inside my database are returned. Entities with the value `Person` in that table are returned. But I want to get every entity.

Also, here are my entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Middlename { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Female : Person
{
    public bool? IsPregnant { get; set; }
}
```

How can I configure my DbContext that `this.Context.Female.ToList()` returns both `Females` and `Persons`. Note that `this.Context.Person.ToList()` already returns everything, not only `Persons`

Comment: You can't. EF gives you exactly what you ask for when doing `this.Context.Female.ToList()`. Suppose it didn't, how would you want to query females only?

Comment: @user2877820 Use `Context.Person` if you want to get every `Person`. Use `Context.Female` if you want to get every `Female`.